# DB2 11.5 LEAD LAG IGNORE NULLS

Tags: sql, function, null, db2, lag

I need to use lag function with ignoring null records.

I am running this script without lag function , but lag function doesn't work with "IGNORE NULLS" parameter.

Any ideas ?

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  READING_TIME  ,
  MEASURE_FIELD, 
  FIRST_value(MEASURE_FIELD ,'IGNORE NULLS' ) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID, trunc(READING_TIME, 'MM') 
         order by READING_TIME asc) as LAST_HOUR_MEASURE,
  FIRST_VALUE(MEASURE_FIELD ,'IGNORE NULLS' ) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID, trunc(READING_TIME) 
         order by READING_TIME desc) as LAST_DAILY_MEASURE,
  LAG(MEASURE_FIELD, 'IGNORE NULLS') 
    OVER (order by READING_TIME desc) as LAG_MEASURE
FROM stg.table t  
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  READING_TIME  ,
  MEASURE_FIELD, 
  LAG(MEASURE_FIELD IGNORE NULLS ) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID, trunc(READING_TIME, 'MM') 
         order by READING_TIME asc) as LAST_HOUR_MEASURE,
  LAG(MEASURE_FIELD ) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID, trunc(READING_TIME) 
         order by READING_TIME desc) ,IGNORE NULLS  as LAST_DAILY_MEASURE,
  LAG(MEASURE_FIELD) 
    OVER (order by READING_TIME desc) IGNORE NULLS as LAG_MEASURE
FROM stg.table t  
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off. Try:

```
select *,
  lag(b, 1, -1, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(order by a) as prev_b
from t
```

For a sample data like:

```
A B
- ------ 
1 101    
2 null
3 103    
4 null
5 105
```

It produces:

```
A B      PREV_B
- ------ ------
1 101        -1   
2 null      101  
3 103       101  
4 null      103  
5 105       103
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c8fd1685a1de2033484bafe3c72c42f2).

**NOTE**: In the `LAG()` function, the third parameter cannot be null (unfortunately). I used `-1` in this example to demonstrate how this value is used when there's no value found by the function.